# How to import GIT into ECLIPSE 3.7.2

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm following a tutorial where I need to import GIT into Eclipse, in the tutorial it is done simply by File/Import/Git/ProjectfromGit ... yet under import I don't have a "Git", I'm on the latest version 3.7.2.

Any ideas where do I get it from? Do I need some plugin or something?

Thnaks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an eclipse plugin called [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/), details for download can be found [here](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/).

Comment: By now it should be mentioned that Eclipse 3.7 only works with EGit 2.0 .. 2.3. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#What_versions_of_Eclipse_does_EGit_target.3F

Answer (score 2):

Yes, install [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/)

Answer (score 1):

Check another plugin for Eclipse [GitEclipse](http://gitclipse.sourceforge.net/index.php) based on [JavaGit](http://javagit.sourceforge.net/).seems dead pls check